# URL Images are not showing on maui windows

Tags: maui, maui-windows

1. App is generated from visual studio 2022 starter for maui
2. Just added Image with `Source="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200"`
3. Image not loading

[image: Output]

`MainPage.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TryingMauiNative.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

           
            <Image
                Source="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200"
                BackgroundColor="#535353"
                HeightRequest="200"
                WidthRequest="200"
                />
            
           
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

`app.manifest`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="TryingMauiNative.WinUI.app"/>

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <!-- The combination of below two tags have the following effect:
           1) Per-Monitor for >= Windows 10 Anniversary Update
           2) System < Windows 10 Anniversary Update
      -->
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

`App.xaml`

```xml
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="TryingMauiNative.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:TryingMauiNative.WinUI">

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

`Package.appmanifest`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity Name="maui-package-name-placeholder" Publisher="CN=User Name" Version="0.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="####hiddenbyme####" PhonePublisherId="####hiddenbyme####"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>$placeholder$</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>User Name</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>$placeholder$.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="$placeholder$"
        Description="$placeholder$"
        Square150x150Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        Square44x44Logo="$placeholder$.png"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="$placeholder$.png" Wide310x150Logo="$placeholder$.png" Square310x310Logo="$placeholder$.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="$placeholder$.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
      <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

Comment: That url appears to redirect to an image.  You need to use the url of the actual image

Comment: Wow. I wasted 5+ hours for this. This worked
`https://images.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2021/01/08/Pictures/planet-earth-europe-and-asia-from-space_813c69fe-51c3-11eb-8a3c-8a727805186f.jpg`
Thanks man!

Comment: Seems that url cannot be resolved. But in Mac the picture appears.